# Improve the performance of dacpac deployment using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, localdb, dacpac

We are deploying to `MS SQL Server` `localdb` for integration testing.

We build a Database Project and the resulting `dacpac` file is copied in order to be used by the IntegrationTests project. So far we have:

```
DatabaseProject.sqlproj
    bin/debug/DatabaseProject.dacpac
IntegrationTests.csproj 
    bin/debug/DatabaseProject.dacpac
```

We have an assembly setup in the IntegrationTests project where a new fresh database is created and the `dacpac` is deployed to `localdb`. In the TearDown the database is deleted so we have a deterministic state for testing.

This is the code that deploys the `dacpac`, which uses `DacServices` (`Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac`, `System.Data.SqlLocalDb`, `System.Data.SqlClient`):

```
public void CreateAndInitializeFromDacpac(
ISqlLocalDbInstance localDbInstance,
string databaseName,
string connectionString,
string dacpacPath)
{

    using (var cx = localDbInstance.CreateConnection())
    {
        cx.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(
            string.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0}", databaseName), cx))
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    var svc = new DacServices(connectionString);

    svc.Deploy(
        DacPackage.Load(dacpacPath),
        databaseName,
        true
        );
}
```

We are having now a couple of database projects, and it takes about **8s** to deploy each one. That increases the overall time to execute the tests.

Is it possible somehow to improve the deploy performance of the `dacpac`?

Comment: Visual studio offers ways to find out  track which statements are taking time,try to fine tune them.if you are not able to fine tune them,try to use parallelism to deploy multiple projects in paralle

Comment: Do you really have to create the database in a separate step? Without testing myself, `dacservices` might be comparing all the objects in the dacpac to their counterparts in the empty database.

Comment: @GavinCampbell, TheGamesiwar, both your comments have been useful, and allowed me to decrease the overall time for 4 databases from 25s to 4.5s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gavin is right!

Don't tear the database down instead use the *Create New Database* option so `SSDT` doesn't have to waste time comparing two models when it knows one is empty.

The code for deployment should be changed to:

```
var dacOptions = new DacDeployOptions { 
               CreateNewDatabase = true
            };

svc.Deploy(
    DacPackage.Load(dacpacPath),
    databaseName,
    true, 
    options: dacOptions
    );
```

There are loads of additional optimizations that `SSDT`can do if you set this flag - if you can be bothered to use reflector have a look at `Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll` and `Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.OnInitialize(SqlDeployment)`. If that flag is set it skips out the whole connect to a database and reverse engineer from the deployed `T-SQL` to the model.

This probably leads to a potential bug where people change the model database to include some objects and then use SSDT to deploy an object that is in the model database but as edge cases go, it sounds pretty low!

Performance can also be improved for the multiple database case by parallelizing the code with `Parallel.Foreach`, as suggested by TheGameiswar.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. I have added the needed code. As I added in the previous comment, I went down from 25s to 4.5s in the initialization of 4 databases.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if there were any "special considerations" for localdb that would stop this approach from working; clearly there aren't!

Comment: Minor note: DacPackage objects are disposable.  I would advise disposing 'em.