# DacPac Deploy - Adjusting Lock Timeout Period

Tags: c#, sql-server, profiling, dacpac

I have a [DacPac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-2017) that I'm [deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43369176/2912011) to multiple databases on the same server at once. Because this puts the server under a great load occasionally you get "Lock Timeouts" on this type of deployment. When I intersected the DacPac deployment in SQL Profiler I noticed that the deployment was setting the "Lock Timeout" to 5 seconds before running the rest of the update statements:

```
set LOCK_TIMEOUT 5000
```

I would like to change that to be something higher, how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This fellow says](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/523c9136-d2db-4f3a-87c7-4451881de00b/lock-timeout-during-sqlpackage-publish-operation?forum=ssdt) you can set that in the "PreDeployment" script. So [following instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-specify-predeployment-or-postdeployment-scripts?view=sql-server-2017), I created a "PreDeployment" script: Script.PreDeployment1.sql, and within that I set the lock timeout to 30 seconds.

```
set LOCK_TIMEOUT 30000
```

Intercepted that in SQL profiler, seems to be being run correctly. Still not the easiest way to accomplish this, I wonder if there is a better way?